# Multi line output in JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to add multiple lines of code to "myContent1" without having to replicate it as this can be quite tedious. Is there a more efficient way? Thanks!

```
function getCode(form){
    myContent1 = document.inputForm.myContent1.checked;
    output =
        '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
        '<html>\n' +
        '<body>\n' +
        ((myContent1) ? '<div>content 1</div>' : '') + '\n' +
        ((myContent1) ? '<div>content 2</div>' : '') + '\n' +
        '' +
        '<\/body>\n' +
        '<\/html>\n';
    document.inputForm.source.value = output;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: have you tried template literals? and I'm not sure why you're putting html and body into there

Comment: Are you talking about the repeated ternary expressions in the middle of your code? The easiest to read option would be to use an `if` block instead, but you could use a single ternary expression to concatenate several strings all at once: `(myContent1 ? '<div>content 1</div><div>content 2</div>' + '<div>content 3</div>' + someVar + '<whatever>' : '')`.

Comment: I do not understand your goal either. I will say HTML ignores newlines and most whitespace, so they are not necessary to build your page. That will save you some characters...

Comment: You got to try [**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: @aduss apparently he is putting that generated HTML in a textarea or something, so he does need newlines and tabs to show as is.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks, then the template literals is indeed the way to go.

Comment: [**Example of template literals**](https://jsfiddle.net/qxoqsxsk/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 Template literals to achieve the same.

This is a sample code. I have modified the code to check the conditions too.

```js
getCode()

function getConditionalTemplate(x, y) {

  if (Number(x) > Number(y)) {
    return `<div>content1</div>`
  } else {
    return `<div>content2</div>`
  }
}

function getCode() {
  const myContent1 = document.getElementById('inputForm');
  const x = 10000;
  const y = 200;

  const output =
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body> 
          ${getConditionalTemplate(`${x}`,`${y}`)}
        <\/body>
        <\/html>`
  myContent1.innerHTML = output;

}
```

```html
<div id="inputForm">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the carriage return after the doctype